# Windows Phone - ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames in code behind

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, storyboard, keyframe

I am trying to create this in code behind. But it is throwing "The Parameter is incorrect" exception.

```
<VisualState x:Name="FlipCard" >
    <Storyboard >
        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Visibility)" Storyboard.TargetName="aceSpades">
            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1">
                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                    <Visibility>Visible</Visibility>
                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
    </Storyboard>
</VisualState>
```

Code behind code is:

```
VisualState vst = (VisualState)FindName("FlipCard");

ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames anim = new ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames();

DiscreteObjectKeyFrame obj = new DiscreteObjectKeyFrame();

obj.Value = Visibility.Visible;
obj.KeyTime = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1);
anim.KeyFrames.Add(obj);

Storyboard.SetTarget(anim, aceSpades.Projection);
Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(anim, new PropertyPath(Image.VisibilityProperty));

vst.Storyboard.Children.Add(anim);

VisualStateManager.GoToState(this, "FlipCard", true);
```

It throwing error in last code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have changed

```
Storyboard.SetTarget(anim, aceSpades.Projection);
```

to

```
Storyboard.SetTargetName(anim, "aceSpades");
```

And it worked.